# R convert colors to pastel colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have a manually designed color palette `pal` that I use for a plot using `ggplot2`

```
 pal <- c("red","red1","red2","red3","grey","darkgreen","skyblue","blue","magenta","magenta4","yellow","orange","pink","pink","black")
```

I would like to convert these colours to pastel colors (i.e high value and low saturation in the HSV color space)

Is there any easy way to do that automatically?

I found the `pastel.colors` from the `RPMG` package, however, this function does not convert given colors.

Comment: Do [`?rgb2hsv`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/rgb2hsv.html) - *grDevices* package - and see the examples for this function.

Comment: @captcoma, try the `library(colorspace)`. See this [cheatsheet](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/colorPaletteCheatsheet.pdf) as well as the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colorspace/colorspace.pdf) for details

Comment: Could be easier to directly use internal pastel palettes such as `RColorBrewer::display.brewer.pal(8, "Pastel1")`

Comment: good inputs! I tried colorspace, however, I cold only chose preset color schemes, same problem with RColorBrewer, Pastel1 gives me 9 preset colors. What I need the 13 colors I mention as pastels in the identical sequence. Is it probably the best to add the pastels manually?

Comment: The development version of `colorspace` has a function `lighten` that you can use to lighten all your colors by a certain amount

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I'm not a color expert you can try following as a starting point. The idea is based on a statment I found somewhere that pastel colors 1) have high value and low to intermediate saturation in the  HSV color space or 2)  need some value of luminence. So I transform the names of the colors to hues which are input for `hcl` via `col2rgb` & `rgb2hsv`.

```
a <-c("red","red1","red2","red3","grey","darkgreen","skyblue","blue","magenta","magenta4","yellow","orange","pink","pink","black")
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
barplot(seq_along(a), col=a, main="original")
# transform to rgb
a1 <- col2rgb(a)
# transform to HSV space
a2 <- rgb2hsv(a1)
# you can try different scaling values e.g. between 0.3 - 0.6
n <- 0.4
barplot(seq_along(a), col=hsv(a2[1,], a2[2,]*n, a2[3,]), main="Pastel_hsv")
# calculate hue for HCl
hue <- a2["h",]*360
# create color with suitable chroma and luminance to get pastel color
a3 <- hcl(hue, 35, 85)
barplot(seq_along(a), col=a3, main="Pastel_hcl")
```

[image]