# Matplotlib: convert colormap to pastel colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, color-scheme

I am currently using color shades from [single color matplotlib colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) (like `Blues`, `Purples`, `Greens`). However I would prefer softer, "pastel" tones. How could I soften the existing colormaps or perhaps there are more appropriate colormaps to use for this purpose?

**Remark:** my question is essentially a python version of this one: [R convert colors to pastel colors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50600425/6151828).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I have adopted the solution used by painters to obtain pastel colors: mixing the color with white paint. In pythonic terms, if I want to chose, e.g., `n` shades of blue, I take

```
n = 15
colors = (1. - c) * plt.get_cmap("Blues_r")(np.linspace(0., 1., n)) + c * np.ones((n, 4))
plt.scatter(np.arange(n),np.ones(n), c=colors, s=180)
plt.show()
```

where `c` controls the degree of "softness/pastelness". Thus, for `c=0` the pure color is
[image]

for `c=0.2`
[image]

for `c=0.4`
[image]